# Has neutrinoless double-beta decay been observed?

Tags: radiation, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

After searching on this question in the archives here, it would appear that as of 2018, [neutrinoless double beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_beta_decay) had still not been observed. Has the situation changed since then? Can anybody share the current state of the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect any clear positive results would have shaken the world. This very month, there is a new negative limit, and I assume all comparable/competitive ones are also cited in [it](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.181802):

- New Limit for Neutrinoless Double-Beta Decay of
  $^{100}$Mo from the CUPID-Mo Experiment,
  E. Armengaud et al. (CUPID-Mo Collaboration)
  *Phys Rev Lett* **126** 181802 – Published 3 May 2021